# Laravel 3 Validation of a single input form

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-3

I am using spectacular Laravel Framework but i have a validation issue that i cannot solve in any way trying to validate a single email field.

My form input is:

```
{{ Form::email('email', Input::old('email'), array('id' => 'email', 'class' => 'span4', 'placeholder' => Lang::line('newsletter.email')->get($lang), 'novalidate' => 'novalidate')) }}
```

My controller

```
public function post_newsletter() {

    $email = Input::get('email');

    $v = Newsletter::validator($email, Newsletter::$rules);

    if($v !== true)
    { ... }
    else 
    { ... }
}
```

and my model

```
class Newsletter extends Eloquent {

/**
 * Newsletter validation rules
 */
public static $rules = array(
    'email' => 'required|email|unique:newsletters'
);

/**
 * Input validation
 */
public static function validator($attributes, $rules) {
    $v = Validator::make($attributes, $rules);

    return $v->fails() ? $v : true;
}
}
```

I ve done this so many times with success with much complicated forms but now even if i enter a valid email i get an error message about required fied etc Am I missing something? Maybe is the fact that i try to validate just one single field? I really don't get it why this happens.

Comment: Have you tried to debug this to see where it's failing exactly? Is it passing when it shouldn't be or failing when it shouldn't be? Try dumping the `Validator` object after running the validation.

Comment: The validation error is that email is required which means that there are my issues and validation doesnt pass the rules but I don't see why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this might be because you're not passing in an array of attributes (or an array of data, basically).

Try using the [`compact`](https://www.php.net/compact) function to generate an array like this.

```
array('email' => $email);
```

Here is how you should do it.

```
$v = Newsletter::validator(compact('email'), Newsletter::$rules);
```

Comment: Yes you are so right. Great and self-documented Laravel says that $attributes in make method is an array. That is why in all other more complicated forms I ve done, validation was fine because I had multiple attributes passed with an array.